# Change security number to X on specific places

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am new in replacing number into some characters in specific places. I have this set of number 123-45-6789 but I need to show only like this XXX-XX-6789. But I need to change only the number not including the "dash".

**Below is my sample code**

```
var mainStr = $("#view_ssn").text(),
    vis = mainStr.slice(-4),
    countNum = '';

for(var i = (mainStr.length)-4; i>0; i--){
    countNum += 'X';
}
$("#view_ssn").text(countNum+vis);
```

**Output**

> XXXXXXX6789

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simply use:

```js
var ssn = "123-45-6789";
var output = ssn.replace(/\d(?=.{5,})/g, "X");
console.log(output);
```

The logic behind the regex pattern `\d(?=.{5,})` is to replace every digit in the input Social Security number which has at least 5 characters in front of it.  This excludes the last 4 digits of the SSN.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be to match the exact allowed pattern and capture the part that you want to keep in group 1.

In the replacement use `XXX-XX` and concatenate it with the group 1 value.

```js
const regex = /^\d{3}-\d{2}(-\d{4}$)/;
const str = "123-45-6789";
console.log(str.replace(regex, (m, g1) => "XXX-XX" + g1));
```